# Basic programming C Question

Tags: c

Ok, so i'm trying to write a program that can check to see if a number is evenly divisible by 2, 3, 4 or 5.

For example if the user enters 8, the output would be:

“8 is divisible by 2”
“8 is divisible by 4”

My program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>


main(){

    int num, even, oddThree, evenFour, oddFive;



    printf("Please Enter A number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    even = (num % 2 == 0);

    oddThree = (num % 3 == 0);

    evenFour = (num % 4 == 0);

    oddFive = (num % 5 == 0);


    if (even){ 

    printf("%d is divisible by 2\n",num);

    }

    if(oddThree) {

    printf("%d is divisible by 3\n",num);

    }


    if (evenFour){ 

    printf("%d is divisible by 4\n", num);

    }

    if (oddFive){ 

    printf("%d is divisible by 5\n", num);

    }

    else { 

    printf("%d is not divisible by 2,3,4 or 5\n", num);

    }

getch(); 

}
```

For some reason when I enter certain numbers, for instance, 12. My output is:

"12 is divisible by 2"
"12 is divisible by 4"
"12 is not divisible by 2,3,4 or 5"

The first two statements are true, but the third is false.

What i'm I doing wrong ?

Comment: You should compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and you should learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`). BTW `<conio.h>` is a non standard header and `getch` is a non standard function. So you should perhaps have tagged your question with some additional tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf("%d is not divisible by 2,3,4 or 5\n", num);
```

Will run all the times

```
(oddFive)
```

is false.
maybe

```
if (!(even || oddThree || evenFour || oddFive)) {
    printf("%d is not divisible by 2,3,4 or 5\n", num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest a slightly different approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  int num;
  int divisors[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
  size_t numDivisors = sizeof divisors / sizeof divisors[0];
  int isDivisible = 0;

  printf( "Gimme a number: " );
  fflush( stdout );

  if ( scanf( "%d", &num ) == 1 )
  {
    size_t i;
    for ( i = 0; i < numDivisors; i++ )
    {
      if ( !(num % divisors[i]) )
      {
        printf( "%d is divisible by %d\n", num, divisors[i] );
        isDivisible = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Bad input, exiting\n" );
    exit( 0 );
  }

  if ( !isDivisible )
  {
    char *sep = "";
    size_t i;

    printf( "%d is not divisible by any of ", num );
    for ( i = 0; i < numDivisors; i++ )
    {
      printf( "%s%d", sep, divisors[i] );
      if ( i == numDivisors - 2 )
        sep = ", or ";
      else
        sep = ", ";
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/div: ./div
Gimme a number: 19
19 is not divisible by any of 2, 3, 4, or 5

[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/div: ./div
Gimme a number: 18
18 is divisible by 2
18 is divisible by 3
```

Instead of creating separate variables for the result of each test, we simply run through the list of divisors in a loop, printing the result as we go.  We keep track of whether any of the divisors work using the `isDivisible` flag.

There are two advantages to this approach.  First, it's a bit more compact and easier to maintain.  Second, you can change the number of divisors and their values by simply adding more items to the `divisors` initializer without having to change any of the program logic itself (up to a point, anyway).  For example, if you wanted to add a check against 7, you would simply change

```
int divisors[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
```

to

```
int divisors[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 7};
```

and recompile.

Given that you're using `conio.h`, you're obviously on a DOS/Windows platform using MSVC or Turbo C or something like that.  This code *should* compile under those compilers, although you may need to include `stdlib.h` or something to get the definition of `size_t`.

For the purpose of this exercise, you shouldn't need anything from `conio`.  If you start the program in a command-line window (instead of launching it from the IDE), you won't need the `getch` statement to keep the window open.

**EDIT**

This version is a bit cleaner - I've separated input and processing from output.  It required turning `isDivisible` into an array and adding a counter, but I think it's better from a stylistic perspective.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
  int num;
  int divisors[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
  size_t numDivisors = sizeof divisors / sizeof divisors[0];
  int isDivisible[sizeof divisors/sizeof divisors[0]] = {0};
  size_t divCount = 0;
  size_t i;

  /**
   * INPUT
   */
  printf( "Gimme a number: " );
  fflush( stdout );

  if ( scanf( "%d", &num ) != 1 )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Bad input\n" );
    exit( 0 );
  }

  /**
   * PROCESSING
   */
  for ( i = 0; i < numDivisors; i++ )
  {
    divCount += (isDivisible[i] = !(num % divisors[i]));
  }

  /**
   * OUTPUT
   */
  printf( "%d is ", num );

  if ( !divCount )
  {
    char *sep = "";
    printf( "not divisible by any of " );
    for ( i = 0; i < numDivisors; i++ )
    {
      printf( "%s%d", sep, divisors[i] );
      if ( i == numDivisors - 2 )
        sep = ", or ";
      else
        sep = ", ";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printf( "divisible by " );
    char *sep = "";

    for ( i = 0; i < numDivisors; i++ )
    {
      if ( isDivisible[i] )
      {
        printf( "%s%d", sep, divisors[i] );

        if ( --divCount > 1 )
          sep = ", ";
        else
          sep = " and ";
      }
    }
  }

  putchar( '\n' );

  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/div: ./div
Gimme a number: 20
20 is divisible by 2, 4 and 5
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/div: ./div
Gimme a number: 19
19 is not divisible by any of 2, 3, 4, or 5
```